# Proper try-catch design

Tags: c++, try-catch

How do I make it so this try-catch doesn't print out the error twice? The code (below) is only supposed to recognize snap, csg, cdh, and cr. It prints it like this:

```
Input Strings:
snap(12345,Charlie Brown,Manager,555-1234).

snap(67890,Lucy,Right Field,555-5678).
csg(CS101,12345,A).

csg(CS101,67890,B).

csgs(CS101,67890,B). // i want to get rid of this

**Error: csgs(CS101,67890,B). // repeat
cdh(CS101,M,9AM).

cr(CS101,1170 TMCB).
```

Here is my code:

```
out << "Input Strings:" << endl;



for (string line; getline(in, line);) {
    out << line;

    try {

        if ("snap(" == line.substr(0, 5)) {
            string studentID = line.substr(5, line.find(',') - 5);
            line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
            string studentName = line.substr(0, line.find(','));
            line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
            string studentAddress = line.substr(0, line.find(','));
            line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
            string studentPhone = line.substr(0, line.find(')'));

            snaps.emplace_back(studentID, studentName, studentAddress, studentPhone);
            continue;
        }
        else if ("csg(" == line.substr(0, 4)) {
            string courseName = line.substr(4, line.find(',') - 4);
            line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
            string studentID = line.substr(0, line.find(','));
            line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
            string studentGrade = line.substr(0, line.find(')'));

            csg.emplace_back(courseName, studentID, studentGrade);
            continue;
        }
        else if ("cdh(" == line.substr(0, 4)) {
            string courseName = line.substr(4, line.find(',') - 4);
            line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
            string courseDay = line.substr(0, line.find(','));
            line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
            string courseTime = line.substr(0, line.find(')'));

            cdh.emplace_back(courseName, courseDay, courseTime);
            continue;
        }
        else if ("cr(" == line.substr(0, 3)) {
            string courseName = line.substr(3, line.find(',') - 3);
            line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
            string courseRoom = line.substr(0, line.find(')'));

            cr.emplace_back(courseName, courseRoom);
            continue;
        }
        throw string(line);

    }
    catch (const runtime_error& error) { out << endl << "**Error: " << error.what(); }
    catch (const string& e) { out << endl << "**Error: " << e; }

}
in.close();
```

Comment: You should throw exceptions, not data, and there is no particular need for exceptions at all here. Just return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to move `out << line;`  so that it prints only when you know you don't have an error.

I can see no need for exceptions in this code. Exceptions should really be reserved for exceptional situations and skipping bad data isn't really that. Also continue statements are generally considered bad style, again because they interrupt the normal flow of a program making it hard to understand.

Here's your code rewritten without exceptions and without continue. All you really need to do is handle the error case in an else clause and move the printing of the line to the end of the loop.

```
out << "Input Strings:" << endl;
for (string line; getline(in, line);) {
    if ("snap(" == line.substr(0, 5)) {
        string studentID = line.substr(5, line.find(',') - 5);
        line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
        string studentName = line.substr(0, line.find(','));
        line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
        string studentAddress = line.substr(0, line.find(','));
        line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
        string studentPhone = line.substr(0, line.find(')'));

        snaps.emplace_back(studentID, studentName, studentAddress, studentPhone);
    }
    else if ("csg(" == line.substr(0, 4)) {
        string courseName = line.substr(4, line.find(',') - 4);
        line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
        string studentID = line.substr(0, line.find(','));
        line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
        string studentGrade = line.substr(0, line.find(')'));

        csg.emplace_back(courseName, studentID, studentGrade);
    }
    else if ("cdh(" == line.substr(0, 4)) {
        string courseName = line.substr(4, line.find(',') - 4);
        line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
        string courseDay = line.substr(0, line.find(','));
        line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
        string courseTime = line.substr(0, line.find(')'));

        cdh.emplace_back(courseName, courseDay, courseTime);
    }
    else if ("cr(" == line.substr(0, 3)) {
        string courseName = line.substr(3, line.find(',') - 3);
        line = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);
        string courseRoom = line.substr(0, line.find(')'));

        cr.emplace_back(courseName, courseRoom);
    }
    else {
        out << endl << "**Error: ";
    }
    out << line << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Strange, because we were required to use a try catch and throw exceptions... plus in his demonstrations to us, my prof. used "continue". Good to know